# HuggingFace Tokenizer: how to get a token for unicodes strings?

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-tokenizers

The following code does not provide a token for the unicode string '\uf0b7':

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
do_lower_case=True) 
test_words = ['crazy', 'character', '\uf0b7']
input_ids = tokenizer(test_words,is_split_into_words=True)
print(f'token ids: {input_ids["input_ids"]}')
# token ids: [101, 4689, 2839, 102]  # <- where is the token for the third word?
```

```py
print(f'word ids:  {input_ids.word_ids()}')
# word ids:  [None, 0, 1, None]   # <- where is the third word (indice 2)?
```

Is there a way to tell the tokenizer to give a token to the unicode word (e.g. the unknown [UKN]  token or anything else)?

I've tried to add a normalizer, but the output is the same:

```py
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
normalizer = normalizers.Sequence([NFD(), StripAccents()])
tokenizer.normalizer = normalizer
input_ids = tokenizer(test_words,is_split_into_words=True)
print(f'token ids: {input_ids["input_ids"]}')
# token ids: [101, 4689, 2839, 102]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your desired Unicode as Special Tokens?

```
    special_tokens_dict = {'additional_special_tokens': ['\uf0b7']}
    num_added_toks = tokenizer.add_special_tokens(special_tokens_dict)
    test_words = ['crazy', 'character', '\uf0b7']
    tokenizer(test_words, is_split_into_words=True)
```

output:

```
{'input_ids': [101, 4689, 2839, 30522, 102], 'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
```

Comment: your solution works. The only "drawback" is that you need to go through all the corpus and find all unicodes which don't have a token in the original tokenizer, but I can live with that.